# PHP Menu - page conditional formating

Tags: php, hyperlink, format, conditional-statements

I have a PHP menu which I include simply via

```
<?php include_once("includes/blog.php") ?>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to reformat the link text in the menu if the linked page is being displayed in the browser - e.g. (simple example)

PHP inserts the following links:

One Two Three Four

If Four is clicked and the page loaded, I would like it to appear as

One Two Three **Four**

Is this possible (I have searched my apologies if I've missed something).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For anyone, who can see the code.

Comment: just check either in url or the new page if there's something that tells you're are in that page. In case, give it a "active" class via CSS

Comment: paste your code that you are using in `includes/blog.php` so that we can tell you how to do it

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that are the correct one or that help you out.

Comment: Thank you all for your rapid offer of support and suggestions. This is the code I have in includes/blog.php:  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Welcome to Photogenix Photographer &loz; Lincoln</h3>  
<h5 style="text-align:center;">
Blogs &#124;   
<a href="http://www.photogenix.biz/blog/">all</a> &#124;   
<a href="http://www.photogenix.biz/blog/wedding-photographer.php">wedding photography</a> &#124;   
<a href="http://www.photogenix.biz/blog/studio-portrait-photography.php">studio &amp; portrait</a> &#124;   
<a href="http://www.photogenix.biz/blog/location-photographer.php">location</a></h5>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this several ways, $_GET vars, $_SESSION data, reading the current page url,

Here is one way to do it....

Make your links so that:

```
//On your actual page
<style>
.bold{ font-weight:bold; }
</style>

//In includes/blog.php
<?php
echo '<a href="pageone.php?id=1" class="'.(($_GET['id'] == "1") ? 'bold' : '').'">One</a>';
echo '<a href="pagetwo.php?id=2" class="'.(($_GET['id'] == "2") ? 'bold' : '').'">Two</a>';
?>
```

You'll need to format that to whatever you have, but hopefully you get the idea.

This part `class="'.(($_GET['id'] == "1") ? 'bold' : '').'"` Means, If $_GET['id'] equals 1, then echo 'bold'.  So if our link that we clicked was pageone.php?id=1, we know we would have a $_GET variable named 'id' that was equal to 1.  So our class would look like: `class="bold"`.  If our page has the `.bold{ font-weight:bold; }` on it, then our selected link will be bold.

If you aren't using any framework that keeps track of your pages, then you can use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to do matching against your link.

See the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

If someone typed in http://www.example.com/pageone.php

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] would contain `/pageone.php`  So you could do some more checking like

if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/pageone.php'){ echo 'bold'; }

This is quite an ugly way of doing it, though it may work for your purposes.

Comment: This looks like it could be the answer, I would bespoke the style class as necessary and add variables to identify each link / page. I pasted my includes code as well as I could to my original question. Fortunately I have stylesheets so I guess I can add the style code to the sheet rather than having it on each individual page. So only 2 files to edit the include and the style sheet. I'll accept this as the answer - but if my code or comments change anything I will monitor this thread

Comment: Actually there would be an issue if the page was accessed directly - there would be no variable in the URL? Is there a solution to that - just unaccepted the answer just while this point is considered? The answer is a massive step forward though.

Comment: I've just accepted the answer because it is a huge step forward for me. If anyone has anything to add though much appreciated.

Comment: I just updated this answer to include hints on using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to check against your page.  You'll have to get a little fancy with it, maybe using a little regex, but if your site is super simple, the examples would work.

Comment: Thank you @senica I'll give your ideas a go. Even if the server idea proves too tricky the first points you made will be great. I'll give it all a try though. Thank you all again. I've visited this community a few times and normally find the questions's already been asked and answered.